# PKCS11 - Select and Decrypt a Key from HSM

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, encryption, pkcs#11, hsm

I am having some issues selecting a key from the HSM and process encrypt/decrypt with it. Found an example on how to generate -> encrypt -> decrypt a key by Amazon which works perfectly fine:

Example by Amazon aws:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudhsm-pkcs11-examples/blob/master/src/encrypt/aes_gcm.c

but in my case I don't want to generate a key and do the whole process, I want so select one and then encrypt -> decrypt it.

Also found this guide here that explains how to search a key:
https://support.p6r.com/p6r/docs/skc/2017.1/pkcs11_example3_ex_pkcs11_3_c.html

And also another example how to encrypt/decrypt a key but again the key is generated and not selected:
https://support.p6r.com/p6r/docs/skc/2017.1/pkcs11_example7_ex_pkcs11_7_c.html

My goal is to:

1. select the key from HSM
2. manually set all needed parameters like IV, AAD, TAG, INPUT
3. process the decrypt of the key

Like this but by code and key selected from HSM:
[https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,'GCM','Hex','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Decrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%27GCM%27,%27Hex%27,%27Raw%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D))

any idea?

Comment: What do you mean with "encrypt the key" and "decrypt the key"? You can encrypt / decrypt *with* a key. Just get the key handle using `FindObject` and then call the right function.

Comment: exactly, already figured that out but thanx for response